# Как добавить метод к существующему классу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Можно ли добавить новый метод (или параметр) в класс `list` (и другие классы по умолчанию)? Или придётся создавать свой класс, похожий на список? Если можно, то как?

Я в начале стал действовать 2 путем, пока не стал думать: "А вдруг можно просто добавить новые методы?" Просто переделывать все методы класса это как-то муторно  и долго.

Плюс к этому, меня заинтересовало можно ли как-то сделать так:

```
def methot(self, argyment1 = 0, *args2)
```

А так:

```
def methot(self, *функции)
   i = 0
   while i != 10
     исполнить(*функции)
     i += 1
```

Comment: создайте новый класс, унаследовав его от нужного класса и добавляйте необходимые методы...

Comment: "Правильный" (с точки зрения ООП) способ добавить свои методы - создать свой класс, наследующийся от исходного стандартного класса. 2 - не понятно что имеется в виду. 3 - внутри добавить цикл, последовательно вызывающий каждую функцию из списка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете наследовать встроенные классы так же, как и любые другие:

```
class MyList(list):
    def size(self):
        return len(self)


my_list = MyList()
my_list.append(1)
my_list.append(2)
my_list.append(3)
print(my_list.size())
```

А передать в метод функции и вызвать их легко:

```
class SomeClass:
    def call_all(self, *functions):
        for f in functions:
            f()


some_class = SomeClass()
some_class.call_all(lambda: print('Первая'), lambda: print('Вторая'))
```

Comment: Спасибо!   А что насчет 2 вопроса?

Comment: Что именно вас интересует? Можно ли передать в метод функции и вызвать их?

Comment: Да, именно это меня интересует